# unable to send the ref value on an event change

Tags: reactjs

When cat checkbox is selected, the value CAT needs to be sent. And when unchecked, the state reverts back to empty string. Currently unable to send value itself on event. This is the code so far:

```
var SL = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
     return {
       cat: '',
       dog: ''
     } 
  },


 sendCheckBoxValue: function(e){
   this.setState({
     cat: this.refs.textInput.value,
     dog: this.refs.textInput.value
   })
  },


 render: function () {
   return (
    <div>
    <p><input type="checkbox" ref="textInput" value={this.state.cat} onChange={this.sendCheckBoxValue}/>CAT</p> 
    <p><input type="checkbox" ref="textInput" value={this.state.dog} onChange={this.sendCheckBoxValue}/>DOG</p> 
  </div>
   )
  } 

})

ReactDOM.render(<SL/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: The answer I picked is not entirely what I wanted. I mixed both the answers and came up with my own logic in the end. But the answer I picked is more useful for me in understanding how to set the state when a condition is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to provide checked instead of value to input checkboxes.

Second thing, you don t need to use refs, since you can get the checkbox checked value from event.target.checked.

Here is the code

```
var SL = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
     return {
       cat: '',
       dog: ''
     } 
  },


 sendCheckBoxValue: function(event,type){
   let state = {}
   if(type === 'cat') state.cat = event.target.checked
   if(type === 'dog') state.dog = event.target.checked
   this.setState(state)
  },


 render: function () {
   return (
    <div>
    <p>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        checked={this.state.cat} 
        onChange={ function(event){ 
           return this.sendCheckBoxValue(event,'cat') 
        }.bind(this) }
      />
      CAT
   </p> 
    <p>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        checked={this.state.dog} 
        onChange={ function(event){ 
           return this.sendCheckBoxValue(event,'dog') 
        }.bind(this) }
      />
      DOG
   </p> 
  </div>
   )
  } 

})

ReactDOM.render(<SL/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gives ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

Comment: Still get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendCheckBoxValue' of undefined`

Comment: And you might think of using es6 features, they handle most of these problems, for instance we could use an arrow function and this would prevent this to lose its context. Take a look at create-react-app which provides out-of-the-box boiler -plate with es6 etc.

Comment: I just noticed that this only sets state as true/false but not the `value` as in the cat/dog to the setstate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using checked attribute instead of value. Also, use different values in your ref attributes:

```
var SL = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
     return {
       cat: false,
       dog: false
     } 
  },


 sendCheckBoxValue: function(e){
   this.setState({
     cat: this.refs.textInput1.checked,
     dog: this.refs.textInput2.checked
   })
  },


 render: function () {
   return (
    <div>
    <p><input type="checkbox" ref="textInput1" value={this.state.cat} onChange={this.sendCheckBoxValue}/>CAT</p> 
    <p><input type="checkbox" ref="textInput2" value={this.state.dog} onChange={this.sendCheckBoxValue}/>DOG</p> 
  </div>
   )
  } 

})

ReactDOM.render(<SL/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```